# How to make a variable be a sequence of file names from a folder in bash? And use two variables in for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I' am trying to make a simple bash script that run multiple times a program with several files at once, thought in make this with a for loop.
that's why I thought in use a seq with the file names, I could set manually but I think is more fun learn how to do this in a more elegant way. Can someone help me?
that's what Iam trying

```
folder=/user/folder/files_1.fi
folder2=/user/folder/files_2.fi
mypath=/path/to/files/

seq1= folder{??}
seq2= folder2{??}

for x,y in seq1 seq2
output= ${x:0:5}

do

program options -1 $mypath/$seq1 -2 $mypath/$seq2 -o $output



done
```

Comment: You need the script to run on multiple files each time? Or on one file at a time? Do the files already exist? Do they have a consistent naming scheme? Can you show sample filenames?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do completely, but you could try using `ls` command. For example ``x=`ls /path/to/files/*` `` will make `x` contain list of all files in the specified directory. Of course you can use it like this: ``x=`ls /path/to/files/prefix*` ``  if you are only interested in files with some specific prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out a way to solve my own problem, and I'am posting here for other looking for the same or similar problem.

Thank you anyway.

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

seq1=(/path/to/files/*._1.fq)
seq2=(/path/to/files/*._2.fq)

for ((i=0;i<=${#seq1[@]};i++)); do

 output=$(echo ${seq1[$i]} | awk '{print substr ($0, 28, 8)}')
program options -1 ${seq1[$i]} -2 ${seq2[$i]} -o $output
done
```

Comment: With **indexed** arrays `${seq1[i]}` works fine, no need for preceding `i` with `$` (treated as in `((...))`). (**note:** the `$` is required with **associative** arrays.)